# Join ids with sums

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a table table1 with columns id and name. I also have a table table2 with columns table1_id and num. What I'm looking to do is get a php array that holds an associative array with name and the sum of the corresponding num. Right now I'm trying a foreach loop to cycle through table1's ids and perform an inner join. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the query, you can use a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) with a subquery that groups table2 by table1_id, and calculates the sum using [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). To get the data into a associative array, use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT t.id, t.name, g.SumNum
    FROM table1 t
      LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT table1_id, SUM(num) SumNum
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY table1_id 
      ) g ON t.id = g.table1_id";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["name"];
    echo $row["SumNum"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "
    SELECT 
      table1.name, 
      SUM(table2.num) AS `sum`
    FROM
      table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
      table2
    ON
      table1.id = table2.table1_id
    GROUP BY 
      table1.id
";

$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $array[] = $row;
}

print_r($array);
```